# When my body is decomposed into all it's elementary particles, do these particles possess more information than my whole body?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, information

If the elementary particles out of which my body is built up are all disconnected, do these particles contain more information than when they were part of my body?

In other words, is the number of (external) degrees of freedom of the disconnected particles greater than the number of the (internal) degrees of freedom of the particles connected together to form my body?

To describe all the loose particles you need very much information, but the information is not very interesting. To describe the information in my body you also need a lot of information, but much more interesting (I think even an alien can see the difference, so it's not context-dependent). In my body the particles have, because they are more or less connected, less possibilities to  move in phase space than the loose particles, but other degrees of freedom come into existence.

This question the same as asking which of the two possibilities has the greater entropy. I suspect the entropy of all the loose particles is greater (of course you have to add energy to my body to evaporate it, like what happened to the poor person after the dropping of the A-bomb in Hiroshima and who's "shadow" is still to see), but nevertheless, I feel that my body has much more freedom to do various things.

Comment: may there is some entanglement relation between individual particle and the whole stuff .

Answer (score 4):

> In other words, is the number of (external) degrees of freedom of the disconnected particles greater than the number of the (internal) degrees of freedom of the particles connected together to form my body?

Sure, imagine what would happen if this was not the case, how would your heart pump unless the muscle fibres did not lose a degree or more of freedom?

> This question the same as asking which of the two possibilities has the greater entropy. I suspect the entropy of all the loose particles is greater (of course you have to add energy to my body to evaporate it, like what happened to the poor person after the dropping of the A-bomb in Hiroshima and who's "shadow" is still to see), but nevertheless, I feel that my body has much more freedom to do various things.

As regards entropy $S= k Ln \Omega$, it's the same answer as your first question, your body as a working "machine" has far less entropy than if all the molecules in it were separate.

As regards information, in your title question, which has more information in it, a DNA strand containing all the details of how to recreate itself, or a loose pile of amino acids?

Comment: So the number of freedom of all the loose elementary particles is far greater than the same elementary particles making up my body because they are restricted in their movements (although new internal degrees of freedom are present). But a gas of elementary particles that come from my body has much less freedom in making different configurations than the same elementary particles that make up my body. I can dance, sing, learn, etc. which can't be said for the gas. I guess we're somewhere between maximum information and minimum information (total order). The two extremes are very

Comment: @Countto10easy to describe. If you know how a little part looks, you know how the whole looks. Of course, the information content of total order and total chaos (like in a gas) is maximal, and although our body lies somewhere in between these extremes, it has the greatest number of possibilities to @ different configurations of the whole, which is why we can do so many things (a gas can only be a gas, despite having the greatest entropy, and a configuration with minimum entropy has only one possible configuration). Of course, the pile of loose amino acids contains the most information.

Comment: @Countto10Does this mean that despite the gas having more information (larger entropy) it's useless information, in contrast to the useful information of my body?

Comment: @Countto10Thanks anyway man! Interesting article!

Comment: @Countto10You're right. For example, I wrote that a pile of amino acids contains more information than the complete DNA string, but now I think that's not true. The entropy is bigger, but the pile doesn't contain  (useful) information how to develop a little baby. And I came to think: a mono-atomic gas has 6N (in phase space) degrees of freedom. But if al the atoms form a diatomic gas. then the total number of gas particles is 1/2N, which means the number of degrees of freedom is 3N+3N(rotation)+3N(vibration)=9N. You would expect it to be smaller (like in the DNA). I'm gonna count to 10 now!!

Comment: You're right! The stuff is more complicated when you dive deeper. I'm gonna ask a question about the 3:2:1 division in diatomic molecules.